# Argument of type 'SanityClient | SanityStegaClient' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SanityClient'

Tags: next.js14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhJSz.png)Argument of type 'SanityClient | SanityStegaClient' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SanityClient'.\n  Type 'SanityStegaClient' is not assignable to type 'SanityClient'.\n    Property '#private' in type 'SanityStegaClient' refers to a different member that cannot be accessed from within type 'SanityClient'.

i hope someone has encountered this issue im really new to next.js learning to build an hotel-management by help of youtuber code with lari

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to the latest Sanity client version to ensure to have at least [v6.10.0](https://github.com/sanity-io/client/releases/tag/v6.10.0) which contains a patch which

> disambiguate SanityClient imports

You can do this by using

```
npm install next-sanity@latest
```

If it is not enough I would recommend importing `SanityClient` from the package `@sanity/client` for the time being

```
import type { SanityClient } from '@sanity/client';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sanity.ts file. use this to import:
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client";

Comment: remember to install @sanity/client package first :D